# Iframe de chat com altura automática

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Estou desenvolvendo um chat em php, está funcionando perfeitamente, no entanto, eu estou com problema na hora de colocar o iframe para o site principal onde o cliente terá acesso, no código ele abre o iframe, mas se eu definir uma altura (height) fixa ou 100% por exemplo, eu não consigo clicar em links ou imagens que esteja abaixo do deste iframe.

O código é esse:

```
 <iframe id="iframe1" style="z-index:999999; background:none; right:0; width:400px; bottom:0; margin: 0;  position:fixed; padding: 0;" height=""  border="0" scrolling="no"  frameborder='0' src='link'></iframe>
```

ex.: ele usa cerca de 60px sem o click, mas quando clicado ele abra cerca de 500px, como posso fazer para que ele abra um height proporcional a fechado ou aberto?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é bem isto que você pede, mas eu fiz para que seja `height: 60px;` normal e depois de clicado ficar `height: 500px;`

Primeiro criei um iframe: http://fiddle.jshell.net/peLr1adu/2/ e dentro dele criei um botão (e um script só para sabermos que foi mesmo clicado).

```
<button id="click">Clique aqui!</button>

document.getElementById("click").onclick = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = "Clicado!";
};
```

Depois usei esse iframe: http://fiddle.jshell.net/veba7wjg/4/ e um script para quando o botão for clicado, fazer o iframe maior

```
<iframe id="chat" name="chat" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" frameborder="0" src="//fiddle.jshell.net/peLr1adu/2/show/light"></iframe>

#chat {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#chat.big {
  height: 500px;
}

window.frames["chat"].document.getElementById("click").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("chat").className = "big";
};
```

Os atributos sandbox no iframe não são precisos se o chat estiver no mesmo dominio que o site.

Comment: Olá, @Ricardo,  é basicamente isso, entretanto, ele tem o java script do chat já, aqui ele em funcionamento: https://hositec.com.br/hositecchats/ o problema é eu conseguir que ele seja puxado para outra pagina sem interferir nos elementos que ficam abaixo dele, que por exemplo, mesmo fechado (sem ser clicado) ele fica com espaço do iframe 500px em cima de botões do site, ai não consigo clickar em nada do site

Comment: O problema é que todo o espaço do iframe está sendo usado, mesmo sem ter clicado para abrir a janela

Comment: Será que pode colocar o chat numa página em que isso aconteça? Na página que você passou parece estar funcionando bem para mim. http://i.imgur.com/pFZPI1I.png - http://i.imgur.com/uYRL1uq.png

Comment: Então, ele funciona legal, o problema é que ao colocar uma pagina normal com links e tudo mais, o iframe do chat cobre os links entendeu? Ou seja ele fica em cima, mesmo fechado ele fica com background transparente mas usa o espaço do iframe cobrindo os outros links do site. ele reserva 500px por exemplo, a pagina está no meu localhost. mas suponha que o site tenha um botão um pouco acima do chat fechado, eu não conseguirei clicar nele por isso

Comment: Sem código ou exemplo com o erro, não consigo ajudar muito :/